# I have a question about displaying the data and html element with condition in django

Tags: html, css, django

I have a `<div>` tag which has bootstrap `card` class inside. Inside that `card` I have some data. Right now I use `default_if_none:"&nbsp;"` to not display the data when the data is none but the `card` class still render out to the template. The question is How can I not display both the data and the `div` tag with `card` class when the data is none? In simple words, When there is no data it won't render `div` tag.

```
<div class="card" style="background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);">
  <div class="card-top">
    <pre class="mt-3"  style="font-size: 16px; left: 0; margin-left: -130px;">
        <code class="prettyprint">
          {{ post.content|default:"&nbsp;" }}
        </code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole card in an `{% if %}`

```
{% if post.content %}
  <div class="card" style="background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);">
    <div class="card-top">
      <pre class="mt-3"  style="font-size: 16px; left: 0; margin-left: -130px;">
          <code class="prettyprint">
            {{ post.content }}
          </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```